# htaccess in subdirectory redirects to main domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I have the following rules for url management which redirect non-www traffic to www and then rewrite some urls. It seems to work fine except when i go to "http://example.com/prosite/" (without www, the first redirection case - "^$"). I would expect this to bring the home page (meaning it should redirect to http://www.example.com/prosite/index.php?page=home) but instead it redirects me to "http://www.example.com". Thanks for your help.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase "/prosite/"

# redirect non-www addresses to www
# redirect condition: hostname does NOT contain 2 or more dots
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "!\.([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])\."
RewriteRule "^(.*)$" "http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/prosite/$1" [R=301,L]

# redirect empty path to home page
RewriteRule "^$" "index.php?page=home" [NC,L]

# redirect page path to corresponding page
RewriteRule "^(home)/?$" "index.php?page=$1" [NC,L]

# redirect all other paths to index.php (without a "page" argument this will show the default page: 404 not found)
RewriteRule "!^index\.php$" "index.php" [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was a browser cache problem. I emptied the cache and it worked.